# Uniform distribution and the convergence in probability.

Tags: uniform-convergence, statistical-inference

Sorry guys, I need your help. Can some one explain me how solve this exercise?

Let $Y$~Uniform$[0 ,1]$, and let $X_n=Y^n$. 
Prove that $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Comment: I’m stuck at the limit formula. I can’t get a result,

Comment: Hint: try showing that $E[X_n] \rightarrow 0$ then use Markov's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

We have that$$
E(X_n)=E(Y^n)=\int_0^1 y^n\,dy=\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$
Then, using Markov's inequality, we have that$$
P(X_n>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E(X_n)}{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{(n+1)\epsilon}\to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $X_n\to 0$ in probability.

Comment: $X_n$ is positive so $P(X_n < -\epsilon) = 0$

Comment: You're right @Michh, it simplifies things. Thanks.

Comment: 1/n+1, the results of the integral.. is right?

Comment: Yes. Note that $\int_0^1 y^n\,dy=\frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^1 (n+1)y^n\,dy=\frac{1}{n+1}\left[ y^{n+1}  \right]_{y=0}^{y=1}=\frac{1}{n+1}$.